# Opencv cant free Mat * memory

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, memory-leaks

I am working on an OpenCV project, and I have to use Mat* s (I don't know why not simply Mat objects!!!). Anyway I am having a hard time with memory management.

```
Mat* m = new Mat ( *MatPointerReturningFunc(..))
or
Mat* m = new Mat ( MatPointerReturningFunc(..)->clone())
```

As I follow these steps in visual studio debug mode, I can see the increasing memory on Task Manager. However whatever I have done I could not free memory of these matrices.

m->release() // wont work because m does not have its own memory space

*(m->refcount)=0 //does not have any effect either.

Delete m // no effect is observed

I am really stuck and I don't know how to fix, related memory leak problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: can you create/post a minimal compilable program to show the behaviour?

Comment: Yes that was my initial thought but i dont see any affect of calling delete on matrix. The memory remains the same on task manager. The moment i initialize m i see an increase of 2MB (a big image) however the moment i delete m there is no freed memory.

Comment: what is " MatPointerReturningFunc(..)"? Where is the image data allocated?

Comment: there are many such functions in the system but say this one is an image transformation function.

Comment: if that finction allocates its own memory you'll probably have to free it. Try Mat* m = MatPointerReturningFunc(..); followed by delete m; and test whether it leaks

Comment: please **do not** use pointers to cv::Mat, it is already intended to act as a smartpointer around the pixel data, and you're wrecking havoc on the refconts, the way you use it.

Comment: Berak thx, i ve never prefered to point to a mat, though the company im working in kimda enforces it :(

Comment: ^^ convince them, that references are the better pointers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible to work with cv::Mat pointers, but (as with all pointers) you have to take extra care of deleting the created objects to give allocated memory free again.

In your sample code it is not clear whether the objects, whose pointers are returned in the functions, will be deleted anywhere. If that is not the case, the reference counting of the cv::Mat pixel data will not work as expected and in addition, some (minor) memory will be leaked by the cv::Mat objects themselves. So short: For every `new cv::Mat` there must be a `delete`, so if there is a `new` in the external function, maybe you have to call a `delete` for it (if the function does not do it by some smart class functionality itself later). More concrete, `Mat* m = new Mat ( *MatPointerReturningFunc(..))` will create a new cv::Mat object which is ok because you can delete it later, BUT the pointer which is returned by the function is lost. Try `cv::Mat * returnedPtr = MatPointerReturningFunc(..);` followed by `cv::Mat * m = new cv::Mat(*returnedPtr);` if you want to create a new Mat object (or just use the returnedPtr without creating new).

Here is some sample code with 2 different Mat Ptr returning functions and some ways to access them with or without leaking.

Important to mention that the "best" way of using Pointers are often smart pointers, which are explicitly given by OpenCV. But even better it is to not use Pointers for cv::Mat objects, because it is much less error prone and there isn't much overhead. The reference counting is very nice and you typically don't use things like `int` or `std::vector` or `std::string` as pointers ;)

```
cv::Mat* MatPointerReturningFunc()
{
    // this function allocates new memory by first creating a new cv::Mat object on heap (just some bytes for the Mat header)
    // and second by allocating new reference counted data in that cv::Mat object (pixel memory = 640*480*3 bytes)
    cv::Mat * functionMat = new cv::Mat(480, 640, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255));

    return functionMat;
}

cv::Mat* MatPointerReturningFunc2(cv::Mat * input)
{
    // this function does not allocate new memory on the heap, just modifies the input data
    cv::circle(*input, cv::Point(320, 240), 100, cv::Scalar(rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255), -1);

    return input;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    while (cv::waitKey(0) != 'q')
    {
        cv::Mat * mainMat;
        cv::Mat * anotherMat;

        // this will not leak, because the memory which was allocated in the function, is destroyed afterwards
        //  and the reference counter of the openCV Mat pixel-data is decremented
        if (true)
        {
            mainMat = MatPointerReturningFunc();
            cv::imshow("main", *mainMat);
            delete mainMat;
        }

        // this will leak because the returned Mat object will not be deleted, only the here created one - that's why the reference counting is stuck at one referenced object
        if (false)
        {
            mainMat = new cv::Mat(*MatPointerReturningFunc());
            delete mainMat;
        }

        // this will not leak, since all references to the Mat data are destroyed (the returned Mat and the locally created new Mat)
        if (true)
        {
            mainMat = MatPointerReturningFunc();
            cv::Mat * anotherMat = new cv::Mat(*mainMat);
            cv::imshow("main", *mainMat);
            cv::imshow("another", *anotherMat);
            cv::imshow("another", *anotherMat);
            delete mainMat;
            delete anotherMat;
        }

        // this will not leak because all references are destroyed
        if (true)
        {
            mainMat = MatPointerReturningFunc();
            cv::imshow("main", *mainMat);
            anotherMat = new cv::Mat(mainMat->clone());
            cv::imshow("another", *anotherMat);
            delete mainMat;
            delete anotherMat;
        }


        // now here we work with the second function which does not allocate new memory but only modifies the input matrix
        if (true)
        {
            // first we have to allocate memory, otherwise the input mat can't be modified ;)
            mainMat = new cv::Mat(480, 640, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));
            cv::imshow("main", *mainMat);

            // this does not leak because the second functions doesn't allocate new memory:
            //  however we have to delete mainMat later, because we created it before.
            if (true)
            {
                anotherMat = MatPointerReturningFunc2(mainMat);
                cv::imshow("another", *anotherMat);
            }

            // this does not leak because we delete the new created Mat object here and the before created mainMat later
            if (true)
            {
                anotherMat = new cv::Mat(*MatPointerReturningFunc2(mainMat));
                cv::imshow("another", *anotherMat);
                delete anotherMat;
            }

            // this does not leak because we delete the new created Mat object here and the before created mainMat later
            //  in fact, this way will allocate new pixel data because of the clone(), but we will free the memory with `delete anotherMat`directly
            if (true)
            {
                anotherMat = new cv::Mat(MatPointerReturningFunc2(mainMat)->clone());
                cv::imshow("another", *anotherMat);
                delete anotherMat;
            }

            // since we created the object and allocated memory, we have to give it free here again
            delete mainMat;
        }

        // in fact, if you WANT to use Pointers with OpenCV Mat objects you should use smart pointers.
        //  OpenCV has its own smart pointers, but I guess you could use any other smart pointers
        // create a Mat object on the heap, allocate pixel data and access all this by a smart pointer!
        cv::Ptr<cv::Mat> smartPtr = new cv::Mat(480, 640, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255) );
        cv::imshow("smart pointer", *smartPtr);

        // no need to delete the created Mat on the smart pointer, because the smart pointer has its own reference counting
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Exactly!!! I should refer to the result of the function and then initialize a new mat ptr clonibg the reference and then remove the reference !!! Thanks a lot!!!! Im sure this comprehensive answer of yours will help many others:)

Comment: please keep in mind that cloning introduces a lot of overhead! Pixel data will be copied and probably the original idea of your company of using pointers there is driven ad absurdum. I would recommend to use the returned pointer directly without creating a copy. But only if you csn be sure that there are no side effects!

Comment: The returned polnter is updated later on thats why I cloned it. However there are cases where cloning is an overhead as well;)